# Concatenate object value to the string variable in html template

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'd stuck at a point while working with `ng` directives. I'm passing two parameters to `mouseoverOnStep` function, one is object value itself and second one is the `selector` of the element. I've the following HTML code

```
<li ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-{{Color.id}}');" ng-repeat="Color in select.Color">&nbsp;</li>
```

What I am getting the output when I inspected my element. It is

```
<li ng-repeat="Color in select.Color" ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-');" class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</li>
```

**With**

```
Error: [$parse:syntax]
```

Why I am not getting the value of `{{Color.id}}` in DOM ?
I am expecting something like.

```
ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-12');"
ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-13');"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't put a brace expression in the function, it is already accepting an angular expression. so change it to pass in the `Color.id` and in the function concatenate it with `'.mask-second-'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already an angular expression:

```
ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-{{Color.id}}');"
```

Putting `{{ }}` into javascript isn't valid.

You have 2 options:

```
ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-'+ Color.id);"
```

This won't evaluate and show the value of `Color.id`, and why should it? it is the same as writing this function in JavaScript:

function showMeId(value) {
console.log(value);
}

showMeId('.mask-second-' + Color.id); // in javascript you will never see that evaluated.

-- OR --

```
ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color);"
```

your `mouseoverOnStep`:

```
function mouseoverOnStep(color) {
    var cssClass = '.mask-second-' + Color.id;
}
```

I think you're getting confused with what is JavaScript and what is HTML and what gets evaluated.

Comment: Pardon your first answer did not work for me. It is giving the output `ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-'+ Color.id);"` instead `ng-mouseover="mouseoverOnStep(Color.color_value, '.mask-second-12');"`. For your second answer I will only have to go with that. I was trying to make a global function so you can call this from everywhere (Views)..

Comment: It won't replace the value, it hasn't been executed by javascript... I'm not sure what you're asking....